# Does a 4 year old Mexican citizen need a Mexican passport to fly within Mexico?

Tags: air-travel, mexico

I will be traveling with my girlfriend and her 4 year old toddler. We are traveling from TJ to Cabo. Does the 4 year old toddler need a passport to fly within Mexico or any other documentation?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Aeromex flight information for passengers](https://www.aeromexico.com/es-mx/informacion-de-vuelos/pasajeros):

**Infants** (7 days to 2 years of age) on domestic flights have to have either a **passport**, or a **birth certificate** (Acta de nacimiento). For journeys originating from the Felipe Ángeles International Airport (NLU), there is an additional option of using a **[CURP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Population_Registry_Code)** for infants.

**Minors** (from 2 years of age) on domestic flights can use any of the following:

- Birth certificate
- CURP
- Valid passport
- Valid school ID with photo

Yes, it's strange that infants can use a CURP only on flights originating from the NLU airport, while there's no such restriction for older minors, but that's what I read on the Aeromex website.

*Disclaimer regarding the "CURP": all Mexican citizens (as well as permanent residents) have this alphanumeric identifier. While it's not mentioned explicitly on the Aeromex website, I believe it's not enough if a child has the CURP identifier issued by the government. Everyone has it. I believe it's necessary to carry an official **card** showing this CURP. But that's my personal opinion, I've never flown with Aeromex and never been to Mexico.*

Comment: The CURP card is in your general list of minor documents. Is it not valid at other airports?

Comment: The aswer was edited by another person and yes, it was a bit unclear. I've edited it again to make it clearer and I've also addressed your question.

Answer (score -1):

Aeromexico on their [Documents](https://www.aeromexico.com/en-us/travel-information/documents-and-visas) page states:

> > For passengers boarding domestic flights, the following identification documents are permitted:
>
> - IMSS Credential with photo
> - FM3 with photo
> - Neighborhood Letter with photo, letterhead, and municipal seal
> - Current Passport
> - Consular ID
> - Valid Driver’s License
> - Professional’s ID
> - Military Service letter
> - Valid voter ID
> - INSEN ID
> - Congressional ID
> - Mexican Nationality Certificate
> - Military ID

Comment: Is this needed for children that are traveling with their mother?

Comment: Nicolas can you please add a short bit which tells OP and others which papers the kid is likely to have and which will be enough.